# how to get font size using pdfbox

Tags: pdfbox

Does anyone know if the method getFontSize in TextPosition always returns one and should I only use getFontSizeInPt to get the size of the font? 
The problem I have is that getFontSizeInPt sometimes returns different values for the same sized text (I got 12 and 11 return for text in the same paragraph with the same size.

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone know if the method getFontSize in TextPosition always returns one

It does not always return one.

Please be aware that in the PDF page content descriptions there are several settings which all influence the final text size:

- the font size parameter of the font selecting operator **Tf**:
- the text matrix set by the operator **Tm**;
- the current transformation matrix set by the operator **cm**;
- the **UserUnit** setting of the PDF page.

The final text size is the first value scaled by the text matrix, scaled again by the transformation matrix, and scaled once more by the user unit value.

(Actually there even are some more factors. E.g. if one uses rendering mode 2, fill & stroke, for a faux bold effect, this slightly increases the size, too.)

`TextPosition.getFontSize` returns the first value only.

`TextPosition.getFontSizeInPt` returns something like the first value scaled by the matrices. (*something like* because at first glance there seems to be another influence in it.)

Different PDF creators use these influences in different ways:

- Some PDF creators use only the first value to set the font size and use the matrices only for operations not changing the effective font size, e.g. rotations.
- Some PDF creators set the first value to 1 and scale using the matrices.
- Some PDF creators fall inbetween and use both the first value and the scaling operations.

Thus, your PDFs seem to be created by software using the second way.

> getFontSizeInPt sometimes returns different values for the same sized text (I got 12 and 11 return for text in the same paragraph with the same size.

Could you share a sample PDF with that issue? As mentioned above, at first glance there seem to be additional influences which might be incorrect. But there also might be something special about your PDF.